pgx scan query with join into nested struct
I have an SQL query that joins 2 tables:
SELECT locations.id as id, locations.name as name, states.id as state.id, states.name as state.name FROM locations INNER JOIN states ON states.id = locations.state_id;

And I have a Location type and a State type defined like this:
type State struct {
  ID uint `db:"id"`
  Name string `db:name"`
}

type Location struct {
  ID uint `db:"id"`
  Name string `db:name"`
  StateID uint `db:"state_id"`
  State *State `db:"state"`
}

I want to be able to scan the results of that query into a Location struct using pgx.
I've tried this but it does not work:
// dbConn is a pgxpool.Pool instance and query is a string with the query shown above
rows, err := dbConn.Query(context.Background(), query, pgx.NamedArgs{})
if (err != nil) { log.Fatal(err) }
location, err := pgx.CollectRows[Location](rows, pgx.RowToStructByNameLax[Location])
if (err != nil) { log.Fatal(err) }

If I ran that code I get an error saying struct doesn't have corresponding row field state.id
I've managed to get around that by manually mapping each row like this:
location := Location{}
state := State{}
err := row.Scan(&location.ID, &location.Name, &state.ID, &state.Name)
if (err != nil) { log.Fatal(err) }
location.State = &state

But I was hoping state.* columns would be mapped automatically to Location.State.* fields.
Can something like that be done using pgx? or it's only possible using a library like scany?
